# Java replace characters in a string except for the given value in a variable

Tags: java

Need some help.
So here is the task:
Create a program that will ask for a main phrase. Ask for a key string value that will be preserved in the phrase. Display a version of the original main phrase where all chars have been replaced by pluses ("+"), except for appearances of the key string value which are preserved unchanged.
Sample outputs:

```
------------------------------------------------
Enter main phrase: 12xy34
Enter key string:xy
New Version: ++xy++
------------------------------------------------
Enter main phrase: 12xy34
Enter key string:1
New Version: 1+++++
------------------------------------------------
Enter main phrase: 12xy34xyabcxy
Enter key string:xy
New Version: ++xy++xy+++xy
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
 public class Corpuz_Kervin
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
         String phrase,key= "";
        String plus = "+";


        System.out.print("Enter main phrase : ");
        phrase = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter key string : ");
        key = input.nextLine();



        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
        {
            char x = phrase.charAt(i);
            if (x.contains(key))
            {
                System.out.print(phrase.replace(x),"+");
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.print("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me
Thanks

Comment: You should post your actual output.

Comment: A better way of thinking about it would be taking a string of `+` signs, and replacing certain positions with the key phrase.  Find all the offsets that the key phrase occurs in the original string, and add those into a string of pluses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead of your loop:

```
System.out.println(phrase.replaceAll("[^" + key + "]", plus));
```

Comment: by the way what is the meaning of this? [^" + key + "]

Comment: @JohnMichaelRivera `^` inside of `[ ]` negates the characters. In your example `[^xy]` means that all characters that aren't the characters in the braces will be replaced. That means that "123xy1y344x" turns into "+++xy+y+++x". Would that be a problem?

Comment: No,i'm just asking for that symbol.Thanks you help me a lot

Comment: This isn't entirely correct - it would also replace xy => "123y123y" with "+++y+++y", which is wrong.  The character class pattern will match on any character in the phrase, not the entire phrase.

Comment: @SamDufel This is what I have written in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

why not use replaceAll with not phrace , use this expression "?!.({your phrase})"

Comment: uhm so how will be the codes there?and where wil i put this expression?

Comment: import java.util.*;
public class Corpuz_Kervin
{
 public static void main (String [] args)
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
  String phrase,key;
  String plus = "+";
  
  
  System.out.print("Enter main phrase : ");
  phrase = input.next();
  System.out.print("Enter key string : ");
  key = input.next();
  for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length();i++)
  {
   char a = phrase.charAt(i);
   for (int j = 0; j < key.length(); j++)
   {
    char b = key.charAt(j);
    if (a.contains(b))
    {
     System.out.print(a.replace(b,plus));
    }
   }  
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a `char` and `key` is a `String`: The condition should not be `x.contains(key)`.

Comment: uhm so what must be the condition?

Comment: import java.util.*;
public class Corpuz_Kervin
{
 public static void main (String [] args)
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
  String phrase,key;
  String plus = "+";
  
  
  System.out.print("Enter main phrase : ");
  phrase = input.next();
  System.out.print("Enter key string : ");
  key = input.next();
  for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length();i++)
  {
   char a = phrase.charAt(i);
   for (int j = 0; j < key.length(); j++)
   {
    char b = key.charAt(j);
    if (a.contains(b))
    {
     System.out.print(a.replace(b,plus));
    }
   }  
  }
 }
}